# How to get port number from receiving Udp packet in php like java

Tags: java, php, sockets, udp

Is there any way to get port number from receiving upd packet in php.....

In java i usually call this function pacet.getPort() and packet.getAddress() to get port number and ip address of sender.

Is there any way to achive this in UDP?

Thanks for advance.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP uses Berkeley style networking, whereas Java wraps it a little bit for you and is easier to use.  In PHP you should receive the data with the function:

```
int socket_recvfrom ( resource $socket , string &$buf , int $len , int $flags , string &$name [, int &$port ])
```

The last argument will contain the remote port on successful return.  To get the address of the sender, use socket_getpeername().